# MySQL query filtering with CASE or IF

Tags: php, mysql, database, if-statement

I am trying to find the most efficient (or proper if you prefer) way to filter a MySQL query.

What I am trying to achieve is from a list of around 20+ checkboxes (which I am using to filter the results) to see which one of them are "checked" and if they are "checked" to add them after the WHERE clause.

When they are "checked" the `$var = '1'` else it is NULL.

What I did until now was mix them together but with 20+ filters that's like o_O

```
if ($var1 == '1') {
    $query = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE var1 = '1';";
    ..
} elseif ($var2 == '1') {
    $query = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE var2 = '1';";
    ..
} elseif ($var1 == '1' AND $var2 == '1') {
    $query = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE var1 = '1' AND var2 = '1';";
    ..
}
```

Combination of 20+ filters seems a bit stupid this way.. Is there a simpler way like put an `IF $var1 != NULL THEN WHERE var1 = '1'`?

Thank you!

Comment: @Marcus gives the REAL solution to this issue in the comments. Name your checkboxes consistently like `checkName[]` and give them value `var1` etc, then looping over your array is cake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do what you need:

```
$var1 = '1';
$var2 = '0';
$var3 = '1';

$where = array('1 = 1');

foreach (array('var1', 'var2', 'var3') as $var)
{

  if ('1' == $$var)
  {
    $where[] = "$var = '1'";
  }

}

// SELECT * FROM table WHERE 1 = 1 AND var1 = '1' AND var3 = '1'  
echo $query = 'SELECT * FROM table WHERE ' . implode(' AND ', $where);
```

Comment: Hello mate and thank you for your reply. I liked your answer most because it doesn't need to be var1, var2, var3 I can use their actual names :) One tiny thing though. Is there a way instead of $var1, $var2, etc to grab $_SESSION['var'] etc

Comment: Found it out! Just change the `if ('1' == $$var)` line! Tyvm!

Answer (score 0):

```
for($i=1;$i<=20;$i++)
{

    if (${'var'.$i} == '1' && ${'var'.$i+1} == '1') 
    {
     $query = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE var$i = '1' AND var.$i+1 = '1';";
    }
    else if (${'var'.$i} == '1')
    {
    $query = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE var$i = '1';";
    }


}
```

[demo](https://eval.in/94717)

Comment: At the end of the loop, the query shall be:
`SELECT * FROM table WHERE var20 = '1';` while he needs to include all the conditions in form:
`SELECT * FROM table WHERE var1 = '1' AND var2=1 and var3=1`; and so on!

Comment: @Marcus check the loop properly :)

Comment: Umm, may be I'm wrong, but could you please explain to me? I would really like to know your approach as I'm not really able to get this. :)

Comment: it will look like this with every iteration of for loop..  if ($var1 == '1') {
    $query = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE var1 = '1';";
   }  if ($var2 == '1') {
    $query = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE var2 = '1';";
   } and so on and also since we are using condition if so i think this approach will work

Comment: But I guess @user needs a single query at the end of the loop rather than having a specific one in each iteration!

Comment: @Marcus as i told its a if condition so finally it depends on the value which satifies the condition ,comm'on its a simple 'if' statement only:)

Comment: This doesn't satisfy the requirements. Note the case where OP mentions if 2 vars exist to write sql as `var1 = '1' AND var2 = '1'`.

Comment: Actually your `if ($var.$i` test doesn't work. see here https://eval.in/94710  That just concatenates the value of $var and the value of $i.

Comment: Still broken. Note how `$var2` is defined yet your query says `var1 = '1'`  See my answer if you need a hint ;)

Comment: @DigitalChris aah that was a blunder from my side,corrected.thanks a lot.https://eval.in/94717 :)

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have named your checkboxes as array of `cb`, so you can use their value as,

```
$cb=$_POST['cb'];
$q='';
for($i=0;$i<count($cb);$i++)
{
 if(isset($cb[$i])&&$cb[$i]!='')
 {
      $q.=' AND var'.($i+1).'=1';
 }
}
$q=trim(' AND');//removes AND from start of string
$query="SELECT * FROM table where $q";
```

Comment: well, then put values of all those checkboxes in an array and then run this loop on that array! Simple as that!

Comment: I mean, when you're submitting the form, get all the values submitted by checkboxes in an array and then apply the loop. Coz it seems the appropriate way!

Answer (score 0):

There are several intersting solutions here; this one will work based on a numbered var scheme and add any variable (if it has length) to the query, not just 1.

You can see it working here: https://eval.in/94701

Here are some setup variables:

```
$numberOfVars = 3;
$var1=4;
$var2=5;
$var3='';
```

Note that `$thevar` actually holds the value of var1, var2, etc for each iteration:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE 1=1 ";
for($i=1;$i<=$numberOfVars;$i++) {
$thevar = ${'var'.$i};
    if ( strLen($thevar) ) {
        $query .= " AND var$i = '$thevar' ";
    }
}
```